# Unity gameobjects and text ui change size and position while changing resolution

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen-resolution

sorry I have to put all of this as an image but I couldn't post this with text as when creating the original post something happened to where it was flagged as spam. I figured this would be the only way?

[image: Original Post:]

Comment: Heres the links to those pictures.

[![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYNab.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYNab.png)

[![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8YW2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8YW2.png)

[![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xatts.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xatts.png)

[![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUYxm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUYxm.png)

Comment: Never post code as images. Try to remove the backticks around all of your text but leave them around the code.

Comment: Thanks for the apology but consider editing your post to include what the actual problem is. Code-only-questions whether they are text or image doesn't help us much.  [ask].

Comment: The image isn't only code? I don't know why the backticks are around the entire writing but the only code block should just start at "using System.Collections" @MickyD

Comment: _"The image isn't only code?"_ - ah I see.  Well posting an image of your _question_ isn't useful in the same way that images of code isn't.  It's not searchable by search engines for one.  Consider posting your code.

Comment: Again i'm sorry about this it's just something happened while originally posting it to where it's marked as spam if I post that same text. I tried re-wording it a bunch of times and had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Unity's UI screen is different from the in-game world space.
For the UI part you can easily fix the issue of the size and position by considering the following:

First thing you need to check is the [Canvas Scaler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-CanvasScaler.html) component which is automaticaly generated on your Canvas gameobject.

[Canvas Scaler Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQuAU.png)

- First under The `UI Scale Mode` you should choose the "Scale with Screen Size" which will make UI elements bigger the bigger the screen is.
- Second is the `Reference Resolution` which is the resolution the UI layout is designed for. If the screen resolution is larger, the UI will be scaled up, and if it's smaller, the UI will be scaled down. A good example is to set the dimensions int something like this (1920x1080) which is the most common landscape resolution.
- Third is the `Screen Match Mode` which is a mode used to scale the canvas area if the aspect ratio of the current resolution doesn't fit the reference resolution. With other words if you change your in-game resolution this will handle your UI elements.
- Fourth is `Match` which will determine if the scaling is using the width or height as reference, or a mix in between. So if your game is in landscape mode you should set it to 0, if it's in portrait mode you should set it to 1.

Last thing to keep in mind that will affect your UI elements position is the [Anchor presets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UIBasicLayout.html) which is part of the `Rect Transform` component on each of your UI elements.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix the gameobjects too then?

Comment: The issue with the gameobjects is probably because you are changing your Camera's orthographic size at runtime.

Comment: Is runtime when the game starts? And with the script I added why would it not work?

Comment: Yes runtime it means the game starts and is running. The script that you are using, it will change the orthographic size of the camera which will lead to moving closer or farther. Your objects have the same size but because the camera changes it makes them look that they are smaller.